# Running PSQL.EXE throws error ordinal 185 could not be found Windows 11

Tags: postgresql, psql

Just installed PostgreSQL PgAdmin 4 on a fresh windows 11 desktop (64 bit professional )

Tried running PSQL.exe and immediately a pop window appears with the message

"The ordinal 185 could not be located in the dynamic link library psql.exe"

Any solution please ?

Comment: Was able to resolve this. Not sure which action helped.

1. Reinstalled. (This time chose to install with Administrator rights. But not sure if I installed normal the first time)
2. Chose to install the server too ( This too am not sure if chose not to install in my previous attempt )

3. Anyway, the problem looks resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this. Not sure which action helped.

1. Reinstalled. (This time chose to install with Administrator rights. But not sure if I installed normal the first time)
2. Chose to install the server too ( This too am not sure if I chose not to install in my previous attempt )
3. Anyway, the problem looks resolved.